# Best way to share data between Parent-Child controllers in my case? (Not sure if I need delegation or shared data state)

Tags: ios

I currently have a controller, EventViewController which users access to either create or view events.

During init, my eventViewController will set isNewEvent depending on whether an event has been passed to init.

I have decided to create a separate view controller, VideoEventController handles the video recording functionality for the event. Hence the relationship between EventVC and VideoVC is essentially Parent-Child.

VideoVC needs to access isNewEvent and possible other variables from the parent controller.

Will it be better to perform dependency injection via prepareForSegue (meaning I will set isNewEvent and other variables that the VideoVC will require to the VideoVC) or can I simply use parentViewController?

Answer (score 1):

Both would probably work well. If you plan on making the child in a very reusable way then I would say to use a delegate so it can easily be used in other locations but if this is the only place where you will be using the child controller then just simply passing data through a property or init function would work just fine.